# Speedup virtualenv creation with numpy and pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, virtualenv, pip

I have multiple virtualenvs on a single machine, but all of them need numpy and pandas. I want to have seperated copies for each virtualenv, but creation of those virtualenvs takes quite some time. Is there some well defined way to precompile numpy and pandas on my machine just once and then to do something like:

```
pip install my_precompiled_numpy
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could make use of the [`wheel`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) package. We do this over at [pandas](http://github.com/pydata/pandas) for our continuous integration builds so that we can basically download them and install them extremely fast.

Take a look at [ci/speedpack/build.sh](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/ci/speedpack/build.sh). This script essentially builds a bunch of wheels that we use (numpy and scipy included) for CI. They are actually stored on server and then pulled from there when travis-ci runs.

Take a look at [ci/install.sh](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/ci/install.sh) to see how the installation process works.

In your situation a server might be overkill, but you could setup a local repo and install wheels from there.

Comment: Do wheels work without development libraries?
It keeps saying `ImportError: /local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so: undefined symbol: dpotrf_`.
What libraries do you install to your CI server for numpy wheel to work?

Comment: I noticed you install numpy from sources with Cython. Why?

Comment: We install from sources so that we can test against multiple versions of numpy and other libs. It was the easiest way for us to speed up our CI iterations without depending on the package manager (even though we ended up installing lapack that way, I'm not sure if Ubuntu tracks multiple versions of numpy et al.). We only build from sources once, so that we can reuse the packages via wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but thought I could add some recent insight. I work on both OSX and Windows on the same project.   I have had numerous delays (mostly just getting the correct files etc) on Windows side in trying to get binary installs for numpy etc.   Have switched to using Anaconda Distribution recently and it does a wonderful job of simplifying life.   It has its own flavour of virtual environments baked in and simplifies life considerably.

http://continuum.io/